# D3 Javascript - Only showing one link in force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create something that allows the user to scroll through an array of different links. The nodes stay the same, but the links change when the user clicks to see the next one.

However, it only shows one link in each array. Some arrays only have one link so that's okay, but the ones with more than one link need to be displayed correctly.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

  //var links =  <?php echo json_encode(array_slice($data["links"], 0, 1)); ?>;
  var links =  <?php echo json_encode($links); ?>;
  var nodes =  <?php echo json_encode($nodes); ?>;
  var count = <?php echo count($data); ?>;
  var data_set = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
  //console.log(data_set);

  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = links;
  max_count = links.length;

function draw()
{

  function update_clique_view(direction)
  {
    geo_long_12_index += direction; 
    if(geo_long_12_index > max_count)
      geo_long_12_index = 0;
    else if(geo_long_12_index < 0)
      geo_long_12_index = max_count - 1;
    current_clique = links[geo_long_12_index]; 
    d3.select("#link_number").remove();
    svg.append("text")
      .attr("id", "link_number")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y", 20)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("opacity", 0.7)
      .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
      .text(geo_long_12_index);
    console.log(current_clique);
    link.data(current_clique);
    force.links(current_clique);
    force.start();
  }

  var width = 800,
      height = 600;

  geo_long_12_index = 0;
  if(links.length > 0)
  {
    current_clique = links[geo_long_12_index]; 
  }

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("rx", "20")
      .attr("ry", "20")
      .style("fill", "#000022")
      .attr("class", "background");

  svg.append("text")
    .attr("id", "link_number")
    .attr("x", width/2)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("opacity", 0.7)
    .style("fill", "#FFFFFF")
    .text(geo_long_12_index);

  // Navigation arrows
  var leftarrow = svg.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "/cgi-bin/images/left_arrow.svg")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("x", (width / 2) - 25)
      .attr("y",20)
      .attr("opacity", 0.7)
      .on("click", function(d,i) {update_clique_view(-1);})
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);})             
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.7);});
  var rightarrow = svg.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href","/cgi-bin/images/right_arrow.svg")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .attr("x", (width / 2) + 35)
      .attr("y",20)
      .attr("opacity", 0.7)
      .on("click", function(d,i) {update_clique_view(1);})
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 1);})             
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("opacity", 0.7);});

  var position_label = svg.append("text")
                  .attr("x", 10)
                  .attr("y", 30);


  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .gravity(.05)
      .distance(100)
      .charge(-100)
      .size([width, height]);


  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(current_clique)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(current_clique)
      .enter().append("line")
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.colour; })
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d.colour; })
      .attr("class", "planet")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("r", 10);})                  
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {d3.select(this).attr("r", 5);});

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });



  });
}
  draw();


</script>
```

var links =  [[{"source":17,"target":22,"orb":0.058311111111109,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":20,"target":21,"orb":0.2079,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":12,"target":15,"orb":0.70274999999998,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":3,"target":21,"orb":1.0416277777778,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":8,"target":12,"orb":0.46322777777775,"colour":"grey"},{"source":8,"target":15,"orb":0.23952222222223,"colour":"grey"},{"source":12,"target":15,"orb":0.70274999999998,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":0,"target":17,"orb":0.71342777777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":0,"target":22,"orb":0.77173888888888,"colour":"grey"},{"source":17,"target":22,"orb":0.058311111111109,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":11,"target":14,"orb":-1.6950111111111,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":8,"target":12,"orb":0.46322777777775,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":8,"orb":0.41579999999996,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":12,"orb":-0.047427777777784,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":15,"orb":0.6553222222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":8,"target":15,"orb":0.23952222222223,"colour":"grey"},{"source":12,"target":15,"orb":0.70274999999998,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":2,"target":16,"orb":1.3296555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":16,"target":18,"orb":-1.0532555555556,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":8,"target":12,"orb":0.46322777777775,"colour":"grey"},{"source":4,"target":7,"orb":-0.53862777777772,"colour":"grey"},{"source":4,"target":8,"orb":-0.12282777777776,"colour":"grey"},{"source":4,"target":12,"orb":-0.5860555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":4,"target":15,"orb":0.11669444444448,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":8,"orb":0.41579999999996,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":12,"orb":-0.047427777777784,"colour":"grey"},{"source":7,"target":15,"orb":0.6553222222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":8,"target":15,"orb":0.23952222222223,"colour":"grey"},{"source":12,"target":15,"orb":0.70274999999998,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":2,"target":13,"orb":0.94762777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":16,"orb":1.3296555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":16,"orb":-0.38202777777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":18,"orb":-0.67122777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":16,"target":18,"orb":-1.0532555555556,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":2,"target":13,"orb":0.94762777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":19,"orb":-1.8974666666667,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":19,"orb":2.8450944444444,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":11,"target":20,"orb":-2.9160166666667,"colour":"grey"},{"source":11,"target":21,"orb":-2.7081166666667,"colour":"grey"},{"source":20,"target":21,"orb":0.2079,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":3,"target":9,"orb":-2.1064388888889,"colour":"grey"},{"source":3,"target":20,"orb":0.83372777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":20,"orb":-2.9401666666667,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":2,"target":9,"orb":2.9672611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":13,"orb":0.94762777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":16,"orb":1.3296555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":13,"orb":2.0196333333333,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":16,"orb":1.6376055555556,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":18,"orb":2.6908611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":16,"orb":-0.38202777777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":18,"orb":-0.67122777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":16,"target":18,"orb":-1.0532555555556,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":2,"target":5,"orb":-2.4144611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":6,"orb":1.3803722222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":19,"orb":-1.8974666666667,"colour":"grey"},{"source":5,"target":6,"orb":-1.0340888888889,"colour":"grey"},{"source":5,"target":18,"orb":2.6908611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":5,"target":19,"orb":-0.51699444444445,"colour":"grey"},{"source":6,"target":18,"orb":1.6567722222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":6,"target":19,"orb":-0.51709444444444,"colour":"grey"},{"source":18,"target":19,"orb":2.1738666666667,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":1,"target":2,"orb":-1.2271277777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":6,"orb":-2.6075,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":13,"orb":-0.27950000000001,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":16,"orb":0.10252777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":18,"orb":-0.95072777777779,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":6,"orb":1.3803722222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":13,"orb":0.94762777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":16,"orb":1.3296555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":6,"target":13,"orb":2.328,"colour":"grey"},{"source":6,"target":16,"orb":2.7100277777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":6,"target":18,"orb":1.6567722222222,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":16,"orb":-0.38202777777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":18,"orb":-0.67122777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":16,"target":18,"orb":-1.0532555555556,"colour":"grey"}],[{"source":1,"target":2,"orb":-1.2271277777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":9,"orb":1.7401333333333,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":13,"orb":-0.27950000000001,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":16,"orb":0.10252777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":1,"target":18,"orb":-0.95072777777779,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":9,"orb":2.9672611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":13,"orb":0.94762777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":16,"orb":1.3296555555555,"colour":"grey"},{"source":2,"target":18,"orb":0.2764,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":13,"orb":2.0196333333333,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":16,"orb":1.6376055555556,"colour":"grey"},{"source":9,"target":18,"orb":2.6908611111111,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":16,"orb":-0.38202777777778,"colour":"grey"},{"source":13,"target":18,"orb":-0.67122777777777,"colour":"grey"},{"source":16,"target":18,"orb":-1.0532555555556,"colour":"grey"}]];

var nodes =  [{"name":"EARTHSUN","colour":"darkgreen"},{"name":"MERCURY","colour":"cyan"},{"name":"VENUS","colour":"magenta"},{"name":"MARS","colour":"red"},{"name":"JUPITER","colour":"gold"},{"name":"SATURN","colour":"darkslategray"},{"name":"URANUS","colour":"blue"},{"name":"NEPTUNE","colour":"blueviolet"},{"name":"PLUTO","colour":"maroon"},{"name":"CHIRON","colour":"orange"},{"name":"CERES","colour":"sandybrown"},{"name":"JUNO","colour":"orchid"},{"name":"PALLAS","colour":"royalblue"},{"name":"VESTA","colour":"pink"},{"name":"SAPPHO","colour":"plum"},{"name":"SEDNA","colour":"slategray"},{"name":"MARSSATURN","colour":null},{"name":"JUPITERSATURN","colour":"brown"},{"name":"SATURNCHIRON","colour":"indianred"},{"name":"SATURNURANUS","colour":null},{"name":"SATURNNEPTUNE","colour":null},{"name":"SATURNPLUTO","colour":null},{"name":"SATURNSEDNA","colour":null}];

Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Hey could you write down what is in **current_clique**. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, the data changes depending on user input, but I've added some sample data to question.

Comment: The first current_clique = [{"source":17,"target":22,"orb":0.058311111111109,"colour":"grey"}]. There's only one link. A subsequent current_clique = [{"source":8,"target":12,"orb":0.46322777777775,"colour":"grey"},{"source":8,"target":15,"orb":0.23952222222223,"colour":"grey"},{"source":12,"target":15,"orb":0.70274999999998,"colour":"grey"}] - here is where the problem lies. The program doesn't display all of the links when there are more than one link.

Comment: Mhh could you maybe create a JSBin example. That would help me to understand your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Is this what you want? http://jsbin.com/soraqo/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Yeah that helps a lot. But I'm still not sure what the question is. You said something with scrolling. But when I scoll nothing happens. The code also has no scroll event. So please again could you tell me how to scroll or what the issue is. MAybe a picture would help that shows when you scrolled or so. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, there are two placeholders for images for the left and right arrows near the top of the blue svg rectangle. When they're clicked, it's supposed to show the next group of links between the nodes. You'll notice the number changes as it scrolls through the different cliques.

Comment: I would really love to help but, I cannot see what you describe in that running example. Sorry Michael.

Comment: Well I understand the problem now. But in the JSFiddle there is missing the arrows because the SVG picture are not correctly linked. So it's much harder to test it there. Could you please fix this?

Comment: Okay I saved a snapshot.

Comment: Well and that means you update the code here and in FSJFiddle? I mean maybe you understand that it's hard to test if you need workarounds and so on. I mean I could find another way to trigger the method. But sharing it in JSFiddle is way better.

Comment: Thanks - I've never used jsbin before. http://jsbin.com/mehinamaha/edit?html,output